# Pass data from array to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have these lines in my code:

it reads/checks what data is in the input

```
inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

this set the value of the second field based on the array var pass = { };

```
myPW.value = pass[inp.value];
```

I have arrays that stored user's input

```
inputData = []; //data from the first field
inputPW = []; //data from the second field
```

so in var pass = { }; it should be look like this

```
var pass = { inputData : inputPW }
```

This is my logic but inputPW from var pass is undefined. So what happened here is that all the username from the local storage is autocompleted, when user typed something from the username field, it will auto sugggest his/her username that he/she submitted. Then after selecting, it will automatically pass the password to the password field. But after documenting it (if u try to submit it again) the password is undefined.

Comment: You want to create an object with `inputData[some_idx]` as `key` and  `inputPW[some_idx]` as value?

Comment: that is right like as exactyly var pass = { inputData[] : inputPW[] }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var pass = inputData.concat(inputPW) ;
```

Comment: but var pass = { }; should be an array because myPW field is getting value from   myPW.value = pass[inp.value]; which is an array that has an key: value and the key is the inp.value

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to do something like below,

```
var labels = [one, two, three];
var data = [A, B, C];

{"one":"A", "two":"B","three":"C"}
```

So if above is the result you want, you can try something like below for your problem.

```
var pass = {};
for (var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
   obj[inputData[i]] = inputPW[i];
}
```

Now if you want a JSON object you can stringify above pass object.

```
var passJSON = JSON.stringify(pass);
```

If you want to concatenate two arrays, you can try,

```
someNewArray = inputData.concat(inputPW)
```

Now you someNewArray contains inputData array elements first and then inputPW array elements.

Comment: can i geet the result that look like this -> var pass = { inputData[] : inputPW[] } as inputData[] as key and inputPW[] as value

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, i think we can't do something like that. But not sure. Can't you accomplish your goal with above implementation.

Comment: there's no data in var pass = { }; I have edited my post, you may check the link to test what I mean